# AVR-GCC Windows vs. Linux

Tags: gcc, arduino, avr, avr-gcc

I'm working on an Arduino project which was being developed on a Windows machine with the Arduino Builder. After having a release candidate, I started developing a Linux docker container that would automatically compile this project once it was pushed to my git remote. However, I noticed that the compiled binary from the Linux container is different from that of the Windows machine, in-spite of the same Arduino version and compilation flags. Is this supposed to happen? Shouldn't AVR-GCC make an equal cross-compilation result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Agreed. Compare two manually triggered compilations (windows/linux) and check the compilation log...  (extended output)

Comment: Make sure you are only comparing the very code, not some debug info or whatever. And of course you code must not use macros like `__DATE__` etc.

Comment: I believe I am compiling a release version with no debug code... I do have a single call to `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros for printing the compile time at the start of the program, but I took a look into the binaries and they are nothing alike, a worst of all the Linux compiled one has much worse performance! I am using the `-O2` and some inline flags to make sure some of my routines take less time to run, and while the Windows version is able to do this, the Linux one is not...

Comment: Have you disabled build-ids? And what is actually different? The content? The size? You could take a look at the two binaries with `avr-objdump` to compare them.

Comment: Are the versions of AVR-GCC the same in both environments?

Comment: @ndim I have not purposely disabled build-ids, but I am not sure how are they configured by default... the content is what differs, the size is also different but not by many bytes.

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier yes they are, I made sure of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after having dug deeper into this issue and confirmed that the toolchains had the same versions (despite the different host OSs), I found out that on Linux I was not giving the linker the `-flto` flag for enabling the link-time optimizer, while doing it on Windows.

So all in all, there was indeed a configuration error on my part, and the code now runs smoothly when compiled on both host OSs.